# Importing attribute sets into Magento programmatically? Magmi?

Tags: import, attribute-set, magmi

Is there any way to import attribute sets into Magento? I'd like to be able to import products into attributes within new attribute sets. I've seen the Magmi import documentation but don't understand the requirements or required csv files to create new attribute sets.

Answer (score 2):

For those who as I try to find an explanation with examples but without success, I'll try to explain my solution.

The main point is that everything is distributed in three files to work with attributes and the fourth file itself for importing products:

- *attributes csv* - attributes file (new functionality);
- *attribute set csv* - attribute sets file (new functionality);
- *attribute set association csv* - a file with links the previously created attributes with the required group (new functionality);
- *product list csv* - standard import file for magmi.

The problem lies in the fact that reading the documentation does not allow understand all aspects clearly. 
Next, I'll try to describe a simple workflow with all the files. I'll create three attributes, one text and two drop-down lists available for filtering.

### [Entity type "Attribute"](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Attribute_set_importer#Entity_type_.22Attribute.22) (*import-attributes.csv*)

```
attribute_code;frontend_label;frontend_input;is_visible_on_front;is_filterable;is_user_defined
frequency;Frequency;text;0;0;1
processor;Processor;select;1;1;1
ram;RAM;select;1;1;1
```

First line - the codes of fileds which can be find through firebug in *Catalog - Attributes - Manage Attributes - Edit Attribute*

- attribute_code - unique attribute code
- frontend_label - name to be displayed to users
- frontend_input - attribute type:

  - text - Text Field
  - textarea - Text Area
  - date - Date
  - boolean - Yes/No
  - multiselect - Multiple Select
  - select - Dropdown
  - price - Price
  - media_image - Media Image
  - weee - Fixed Product Tax
- is_visible_on_front - Visible on Product View Page on Front-end
- is_filterable - Use In Layered Navigation
- is_user_defined - Mark attribute as custom
- other attributes can be checked in the documentation or directly in the Magento admin

### Entity type "Attribute Set" (*import-attribute-sets.csv*)

```
attribute_set_name;magmi:groups
PC characteristics;General,Prices,Meta Information,Images,Recurring Profile,Design,Gift Options,Video
```

- magmi:groups - if you skip this field, you get a blank set of attributes without groups

### Entity type "Attribute to attribute set association" (*import-attribute-association.csv*)

```
attribute_set_name;attribute_code;attribute_group_name
PC characteristics;frequency;General
PC characteristics;processor;General
PC characteristics;ram;General
```

### Magmi Settings

[image: screen shot of Magmi settings]

Then run "Run import" and check the Magento admin, everything should get tucked up correctly.